# Button to connect an association in Rails is not working. Transfer of ownership

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, associations

I am working my first Rails project, an adoption app and trying to bridge an association to a new potential owner in Rails. My controller action is moving through my adoption_request method, but no changes are being persisted to my join table in ActiveRecord. Can someone please tell me what I am missing here?

The app:

Owners sign up or log in to their account. They can add their Ferret using a form. Later, the Owner may want to create an Opportunity listing to adopt/rehome their animal. People browsing should be able to click on an Opportunity they are interested in, which should establish an association in the join table Opportunity, :adopter_id.

My Models:

```rb
class Owner < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  has_many :ferrets, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :opportunities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ferret_adoptions, through: :opportunities, source: :ferret
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ferrets, :opportunities
end


class Ferret < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner
  has_many :opportunities
  has_many :owners, through: :opportunities
end


class Opportunity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ferret
  belongs_to :owner
end
```

In Opportunities Controller, my adoption_request method:

```rb
def adoption_request
  @owner = Owner.find(session[:owner_id])
  @opportunity = Opportunity.find(params[:id])
  @opportunity.adopter_id = [] << current_user.id
  current_user.req_id = [] << @opportunity.id
          
  flash[:message] = "Adoption request submitted."
  redirect_to questions_path
end
```

I am using a button to do this, but I am open to change that if something may work better:

```rb
<button><%= link_to 'Adoption Request', adoption_request_path, method: :post %> <i class='fas fa-heart' style='color:crimson'></i></button>
```

As an Owner when I click the button to make an Adoption Request, I am seeing all the working parts in byebug, and I am being redirected to the next page with the success message as if everything worked, but there is no Association actually being persisted to the database.

I appreciate any feedback you can offer.

Comment: I think you need to call `save` for any assignments to persist.

Comment: What is this supposed to do `current_user.req_id = [] << @opportunity.id`?

Comment: `@opportunity.adopter_id = current_user.id`. Or `@opportunity.adopter_id = ([] << current_user.id)[0]` for maximum goofyness. Seiously though `[] << ` is a very weird way to declare an array. Especially when you don't need an array.

Comment: I would like owner.id to be saved in the join table as opportunity.adopter_id to complete the association. The following is optional, but it would be nice to save the opportunity.id in the Owner's record as req_id as a record of the request.

Comment: Ok, I think I may have fixed the problem. I was indeed overthinking the arrays and read that the shovel method should automatically save in Rails. But I didn't need to do that at all. I just assigned it = and the new associations are showing in console.

Comment: That only happens if you call the shovel method on a has many association `owner.ferrets << ferret`. You're calling it on an empty array - `[] << @opportunity.id == [@opportunity.id]`

Comment: Hmm... It saved to the database successfully, but I am not actually seeing any new association based on the adoption request.

Comment: If you really want to know why nothing is being saved with this code its because you're not calling `@opportunity.save` (or using update) but that really just one issue of many.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that Opportunity should represent something like a listing (it needs a less vague name).

If so you're missing a model and its table if ever want more then one user to be able to respond to an Opportunity:

```
class Owner < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  has_many :ferrets, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :opportunities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :adoption_requests_as_adopter,
    foreign_key: :adopter_id,
    class_name: 'AdoptionRequest'
  has_many :adoption_requests_as_owner,
    through: :opportunities,
    source: :adoption_requests
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ferrets, :opportunities
end

class Ferret < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner
  has_many :opportunities
  has_many :owners, through: :opportunities
  has_many :adoption_requests, through: :opportunities
end

class Opportunity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ferret
  belongs_to :owner 
  has_many :adoption_requests
end

class AdoptionRequest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :adopter, class_name: 'Owner' # ???
  belongs_to :opportunity
  has_one :ferret, through: :opportunity
  has_one :owner, through: :opportunity
end
```

If you just have a `adopter_id` on your `opportunities` table it can only ever hold a single value.

I would just set the route / controller up as a normal CRUD controller for a nested resource:

```
# routes.rb
resources :opportunities do
  resources :adoption_requests, only: [:create, :index]
end
```

```
<%= button_to "Adopt this ferret", opportunity_adoption_requests_path(@opportunity), method: :post %>
```

```
class AdoptionRequestsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_opportunity

  # @todo authorize so that it can only be viewed by the owner
  # GET /opportunities/1/adoption_requests
  def index
    @adoption_requests = @opportunity.adoption_requests
  end

  # @todo authorize so that a current owner can't create adoption_requests
  #   for their own ferrets
  # POST /opportunities/1/adoption_requests
  def create
    @adoption_request = @opportunity.adoption_requests.new(
      adopter: current_user
    )
    if @adoption_request.save
      redirect_to @opportunity, notice: 'Thank you for your reply! The owner of the ferret will be notified.'
      # @todo send notification to owner
    else
      redirect_to @opportunity, notice: 'Oh noes!'
    end
  end

  private

  def set_opportunity 
    @opportunity = Opportunity.find(params[:opportunity_id])
  end
end
```

Its only later when the owner actually accepts a adoption_request that you will actually update the opportunity and this is a seperate question for a later time.

Comment: As I've been working I realized the need for an additional table, but the relations have been difficult to wrap my head around. I truly appreciate your feedback here.

Comment: It helps if you try to think about it not just as join tables but as actual objects in your domain and if you use a notepad or a UML tool to sketch up the domain before you even start writing the code.